# AngularJS Animations ng-switch ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, animation, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-switch

I am trying to do what looks like a simple process: to display a list of items received from an HTTP request with animation.

First of all, here is my way of doing it ( I am open to any suggestions to do it in a better angular way ):

- I define a scope variable `state` that I initialize to `loading` in my controller and that I change to `loaded` when I receive data from the HTTP request.
- I initialize a scope variable `items` with the received data.
- In my view, I use `ng-switch` for the states, and `ng-repeat` with the items.
- I define an animation with css on `ng-repeat`.

Here is [a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WVTnGnWsP5jU1rQsnE52?p=preview) ( with a $timeout instead of the request ).

I cannot understand why the animation does not work.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is happening is because your `ng-when`. The same thing happens with `ng-if`, but would work fine if you used `ng-show`.

The problem is that when your `ng-when` condition returns true, the `ng-when` first renders it's content in a detatched dom (so animations do not happen). This dom is then attached to the dom tree (this step is animated but you would have to put your animation class on the ng-when).

When using something like `ng-show` or `ng-hide` things work as expected because the dom is always attached (it is simply shown/hidden).

This might be considered either a bug or a limitation of ng-animate, you might want to post a github issue and see if the angular guys have any thoughts.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have also tried with `ng-show` and then figured out it had something to do with the dom as it was working with this directive, so thank you again for the clear explanation. As I said in my comment of the previous answer, my website is more complex than my example. Even if I can make things work with `ng-hide` / `ng-show`, do you think is best practice for what I intend to do?

Comment: ng-show will typically be less performant because all watches in that dom will still be processed at each $digest() cycle even if the content is hidden, but this might be perfectly fine (if your page is just showing loading....) there's nothing going on anyways so watches aren't getting triggered until loading is done, at which point you WANT them to be triggered. It is more of an issue if you are hiding a bunch of different dom trees and only showing one at a time. Then you should consider better solutions, such as routing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a "feature" of angular that it won't add `.ng-enter` to repeat items inside `ng-switch-when` block. You can remove `ng-switch-when="loaded"` and it will work (You don't really need it as `ng-repeat` won't do anything if there is no items)

```
<div ng-switch="state">
  <div ng-switch-when="loading">
    <p>Please wait...</p>
  </div>
  <div >
    <ul ng-repeat="item in items" class="animate-items">
      <li>{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ocEj7BSQPSeIdnnfAOIE?p=preview

Comment: First of all, thank you for the quick answer. I have tried it and it works well with the example. The problem is that my website is more complex as my example was only used for clarity. It does not just contain a `ng-repeat` but other stuff encapsulated in the `ng-switch="loaded"` and I cannot have it displayed when data is loading.